# How to effectively use NSMutableDictionaries as keys for a dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I want to use `NSMutableDictionary` instances as keys for another `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *stuff = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableDictionary *first = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [stuff setObject:@"A" forKey:first];
    NSLog(@"I GOT %@",[stuff objectForKey:first]);
```

This outputs `@"A"`, as expected, which is fine.

However, if afterwards I modify the values within the `first` object like this:

```
[first setObject:@"C" forKey:@"Something"];
```

I am now unable to get `@"A"`:

```
NSLog(@"I GOT %@",[stuff objectForKey:first]);
```

Which outputs `nil`.

I assumed that `objectForKey` would compare the key's memory address with the existing keys within the dictionary - since such memory address doesn't change despite changing a dictionary's internal values (I think), I expected it would work.

I managed to get it working with a different approach - by instead using `NSString`s for the keys - the value of the strings would be the memory address itself, like this:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *stuff = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableDictionary *first = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [stuff setObject:@"A" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p",first]];
    [first setObject:@"C" forKey:@"Something"];
    NSLog(@"I GOT %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p",first]);
```

Which does work, printing `@"A"`.

My question:

- Why is my original approach not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dictionary takes a copy of its key when it is set (and that copy is non-mutable). When you then mutate the object you used for the key, it and the copy no longer compare equal: `NSDictionary` uses `hash` and `isEqual:` when checking keys. (Collections don't use the objects' addresses in those methods to decide if they're equal, and even if they did, the copy and the original have different addresses.) Thus you can't retrieve the value. If you re-mutate the dictionary to what it was, the retrieval will succeed.

The string trick you came up with is a good workaround; you can also use `+[NSValue valueWithNonRetainedObject:]` for this purpose. Since the address of the key dictionary doesn't change when you just *mutate* it, you can still get the same value to look up afterwards.

Comment: I see, but the memory address will always remain the same?

Comment: The memory addresses of the copy and the original key are _not_ the same.

Comment: In fact the very definition of `copy` means that a new object, at a new place in memory, is created.

Comment: @Omega: Because the address of the object doesn't change when you _mutate_ it.

Comment: I see. Thanks, it was of great help!

Comment: @JoshCaswell Doesn't `copy` return a new `NSDictionary` (immutable) when sent to `NSMutableDictionary`?

Comment: @H2CO3: Certainly. Do I seem to imply otherwise?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Maybe I just didn't get the point in these comments (starting from Omega asking about his second try).

Answer (score 2):

> I assumed that objectForKey would compare the key's memory address with the existing keys within the dictionary

Wrong on multiple levels.

If keys were compared by memory address, there would be no realiable way to get an object for a key. What if you used the constant string `@"Foo"` as the key, and at runtime, you passed another `NSString` instance with the contents `Foo` but it was a different object (and thus its memory address was completely different)?

So no. What `objectForKey:` does instead is sending the `isEqual:` message to the keys to decide if they are equal. This method is, by default, impemented in `NSObject` and it does indeed compare memory addresses, but it's overridden in most standard collection classes for which it's sensible (for `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc.) and it does a semantically more correct, content-related comparison.

Also, keys of `NSDicionary` are **copied** when a key-object pair is set. This means that if direct pointer comparison was used, **there would be no way of getting any object at all,** since a copy is a different object, another actual instance of an object, of which the pointer points to somewhere else (obviously). (Sidenote: this is not entirely true for some immutable Cocoa classes like `NSString`, where `copy` is essentially implemented using `retain`, but you should get the concept).